# What is meaning of Ui-Component tags in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, tags

Please Explain me what is meaning of Below Ui-Componet tags :-

**1.)**

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">mag_mcf_index_grid.mag_mcf_index_grid.custom_mcf_columns.ids</item>
 </item>
```

**2.Why use this :- )**

```
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mag_mcf_index_grid.mag_mcf_index_grid_data_source</item>
<item name="deps" xsi:type="string">mag_mcf_index_grid.mag_mcf_index_grid_data_source</item>
```

**3.)**

```
<item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">custom_mcf_columns</item>
```

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

my humble ideas to feed the debate are:

1. with uicomponent layout configuration, we can create a config node. Any child of this config element do become available afterwards in the javascript component object. Given the name `selectProvider`, I'd give a bet this specific child is dedicated at sourcing the data for a select element.
2. we mention `provider` as well; ui component do have this quite common structure like software programming of decoupling how the data is dealt with. We have a dataSource and we have a layer that renders the data. The provider is the datasource for the grid in this case. For deps, I pass..
3. it is just a child within the overall ui component and this child is the one that powers the spinning effect when any standard action for the grid is triggered. For instance, sorting column, trigger a search..